# AdMob banner: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have a WKWebView which loads a URL, and an AdMob banner view is displayed at the bottom of the WKWebView. However, I keep getting the error: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' when I run the app.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!

var webView : WKWebView!
var progressView : UIProgressView!

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
        progressView.progress = Float(webView.estimatedProgress)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Open", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(openTapped))
    progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    progressView.sizeToFit()
    let progressButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: progressView)
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))

    toolbarItems = [progressButton, spacer, refresh]
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)

    loadAd()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func loadAd() {
    bannerView.isHidden = true   //error happens at this line

    bannerView.delegate = self

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-..." //id is here
    bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}

func openTapped() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Open page…", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "apple.com", style: .default, handler: openPage))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "hackingwithswift.com", style: .default, handler: openPage))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    present(ac, animated: true)

    ac.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
}

func openPage(action: UIAlertAction) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://" + action.title!)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    title = webView.title
}

func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.isHidden = false
}

func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    bannerView.isHidden = true
}
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing this error - the console provides no detail about what optional value it is referring to. The WKWebView worked fine before I tried to add the banner ad, so I assume it's something to do with it.

Update: this shows up in the console:
Printing description of self.bannerView:
expression produced error: error: /var/folders/yn/kndnb8ws7bz1r0rc11fnpndw0000gn/T/./lldb/485/expr3.swift:1:99: error: use of undeclared type 'GoogleMobileAds'
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer>(bitPattern: 0x11b5272a0)!.pointee)
                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: If it happens on that line then `bannerView` is the only thing that can be nil.

Comment: @Scott B. You should use guard let to handle nil values so that app doesn't crashes and you can debug reason.

Comment: Do you use cocoapods for admob?

Comment: If you use cocoapods, check your podfile if it includes `use_frameworks!`. If it's not included, add it and run `pod install` again. After that clean, build and run your project

Comment: Nope, I didn’t use cocoapods, I just dropped the google ads framework into my project and made sure copy items if needed was checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and was able to resolve it. This might help someone...

My problem was that I had not set an IBOutlet Variable, and instead had

```
var bannerView: GADBannerView!
```

but instead I needed to attach my view from my storyboard to my ViewController with an IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!
```

I'd make sure that its linked correctly.

Along with that I removed the code that was programmatically adding the bannerView to the story board. I think this also causes some issues if you mix the storyboard, and programmatically adding it

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you didn't connect the 'bannerView' IBOutlet variable and the relevant storyboard view.

Comment: I reconnected it and the same thing still happens, so that's not the problem

Comment: Are you sure that in the storyboard your view is an instance of the GADBannerView class?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is as it says it in the identity inspector